# Creative SDK Image component - IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, adobe, adobecreativesdk

How can I integrate Creative SDK Image component in swift? I followed all step given by "Using the Image Editing Component - Adobe".

And I also import `"<AdobeCreativeSDKImage/AdobeCreativeSDKImage.h>"` in "Bridging-Header.h" , But when I import Adobecreativesdkimage in AppDelegate it gives me error like "Framework not found".

Comment: did you try to use methods of sdk image after importing it into bridging header only?

Comment: @wolverine I cant try, because without importing framework , how can i implement  method ?

Comment: you have import in bridging header then might be it not required to import again in your swift file.

Answer (score 1):

Try copying the framework into your project folder, import the framework from this location, then check the Framework Search Paths setting in the Search Paths section under Build Settings.  The values you want are:

```
$(inherited)
$(PROJECT_DIR)/AdobeCreativeSDKDynamicFrameworks
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

If this doesn't work, verify your headers are imported from `[].framework/Versions/A/Headers`.

These steps helped fix our first projects using the CreativeSDKs where we followed the documented steps to the letter.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the framework search path points to the CSDK Frameworks folder. If that does not work let me know.